# What is nfsd on macOS?

Tags: macos, launchd, nfs, daemons

I have two questions regarding `nfsd` on OS X:

1. What is managing the start/stop phase of this daemon? Launchd? It has an enable and disable mode, but I don't know what does this do.
2. What is the default status of this service. Enabled or disabled? Should I leave it on disable if my `/etc/exports` file is empty?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

nfsd is invoked by launchd while booting by the accompanying com.apple.nfsd.plist file in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/.

As you can see close to the bottom of the following picture,

[image: com.apple.nfsd.plist]

it's only kept alive, when /etc/exports exists. If the path doesn't exist, nfsd will not run.

So removing /etc/exports will disable nfsd temporarily until the path is recreated

or executing

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist
```

will disable it permanently - even after reinstating /etc/exports (not recommended).

Comment: What GUI did you use on the screenshot?

Comment: @zsero It's [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) coded by soma-zone.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I did a tiny test. If I leave it on enabled without the exports file, I get the following log on every boot: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=X1CJyPmA I think it might delay the boot process a bit. I'd be really curious what is the default state on a clean install.

Comment: @zsero The default state is indeed enabled on all my Macs/VMs. I think the message is provoked by an outdated but cached plist file.

Comment: It seems to be triggered by `nfsd disable|enable`. If I do that the override warning appears in the GUI app and the conditions are not checked at start. The fix is to remove the override.

Comment: please correct /System/Library/LaunchDaemons

Comment: @freedev Thanx - stupid mistake...